# global section of a B-scheme defines a morphism to projective $B$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

This is problem 7.3.O in Vakil's AG notes (July 31, 2023 version). I am not sure how to define the map locally.

**Problem 7.3.O.** Let $B$ be a ring and $X$ a $B$-scheme. Suppose $f_0,\cdots,f_n$ are n+1 functions on $X$ with no common zeros, then show that $[f_0,\cdots,f_n]$ gives a morphism of $B$-schemes $X\to\mathbb{P}_B^n$.

**My approach.** If I understand correctly, by values of a global section $f$ at a point $x\in X$, Vakil means the image of $f$ under the composition
$$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$$
Now I want to glue morphisms defined on the open affine covering $\{U_i\cong\operatorname{Spec}A_i\}_{i\in I}$ described by these global sections $f_1,\cdots,f_n\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. So I start by defining the scheme morphism $f_i:U_i\to \mathbb{P}^n_B$:
$$\mathfrak{p}\to [f_0(\mathfrak{p}),\cdots,f_n(\mathfrak{p})]=(f_i(\mathfrak{p})x_j-f_j(\mathfrak{p})x_i| i,j=0,1,\cdots,n)$$
I think this should be fine, since these $f_i$'s do not have common zero. But I am not sure what to do with their values $f_i(\mathfrak{p})\in \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$, as $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})\nsubseteq B$. If I could solve this issue, then I can define a homogeneous ideal corresponding to the homogeneous coordinate $[f_0(\mathfrak{p}),\cdots,f_n(\mathfrak{p})]$. And I can keep going and possibly prove that they agree on overlaps, hence glue to a morphism.

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: To be honest, this is not the right way to think of it. The scheme $ \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Z}} $ represents a functor, see Hartshorne Chapter 2, Section 7 for how to define a morphism into projective space.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you for pointing out! But do you mean the way I think of the value of a global section? Or my approach in general? Also, this should be possible to solve with the knowledge so far in the context, which does not include that from II.7 in Hartshorne, I guess.

Comment: The way you think of ‘value’ is correct. However, k(P) is not in B (you’re correct there too), rather k(P) is an extension of k(Q) where P maps to Q in B. And you’re supposed to think of the map at P as mapping into projective space over k(Q).